# Finding a Unit Vector v for a Matrix A such that the 2-norm of AV is equal to the 2-norm of A

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, orthonormal

I have been working on the following problem:

Let A be the following 2x2 matrix: A = [1 1; 0 1] (MATLAB notation)

Find the 2-norm of A and a unit vector v such that the 2-norm of Av = the 2-norm of A.

I know that the 2-norm of A is (1+sqrt(5))/2, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to find such a vector v. How should I go about this?

Comment: How did you figure out the norm of $A$?

Comment: I did it out by hand and then checked it on MATLAB.

Comment: The unit vector you're looking for is exactly that one on which $A$ attains its maximum, i.e. $\|Av\|$ is maximal.

Comment: I'm still not sure what that means/how to find it. Find norm(A), I looked for t in [-pi, pi] that maximized sqrt[1+sin(2t)+0.5(1-cos(2t)]. I differentiated, set equal to zero, and did some algebra to obtain tan(2t) = -2. Then I found the max at cos(2t_ = -1/sqrt(5) and sin(2t) = 2/sqrt(5). I plugged that back in to get norm(A) = sqrt(1.5 + 2/sqrt(5) + 1/2sqrt(5)) = (1+sqrt5)/2. But I don't know what unit vector that's on.

Comment: $\lambda = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the largest eigenvalue for the matrix $A$.  What you want is the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: But according to MATLAB, the only eigenvalue is 1 (with multiplicity 2).

Answer (score 1):

The 2-norm of a matrix is just its largest singular value. So, your $v$ is the associated singular vector.

> `A=[1 1;0 1]; [U,S,V]=svd(A); v=V(:,1), [norm(A*v), S(1), norm(A)]`
>
> `v =`
>
> `0.5257`
>
> `0.8507`
>
> `ans =`
>
> `1.6180    1.6180    1.6180`